# Reloading image on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am trying to make an image reload each time I reload the page and I am trying this code:

```
d = new Date();
$("#myimg").attr("src", "/myimg.jpg?"+d.getTime());
```

Can someone help me add this code to a page???

I have this very stubborn piece of code:

```html
<head>
  <script>
    d = new Date();
    ("#myimg").attr("src", "http://i66.tinypic.com/6fme5c.jp?d=" + d.getTime());
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/6fme5c.jpg" class="resize">
  <img src="myimg" class="resize" id="myimg">
</body>
```

Chrome does nto understand what myimg is(:

Comment: your code is missing a $ on `d = new Date(); ("#myimg")`

Comment: Your script is in the head. Your DOM isn't ready yet. Put the script tag at the end of your HTML

Comment: thank you - can you please check this code: https://jsfiddle.net/6knfz8g2/     not sure what is I am doing wrong(

Comment: You need to add a document.ready handler around your jQuery code, otherwise it runs before the DOM is ready: http://jsfiddle.net/6knfz8g2/1/

Comment: As a side note, you'll now put in browser's cache all these 'versions' of same image. If image comes from your own server, you should use [HTTP ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)

Comment: "stubborn piece of code" LOL

Comment: I have updated your JSFiddle, it now works.

Comment: Try to put script tag at the bottom of page to ensure DOM is ready.

Comment: thank you - it works!) fantastic - still a mystery to me why the image would not load without these lines:  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"

Comment: Lewis Browne -   the image loads but I still get this error in console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  -------why?????:(

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues as to why your code is not working;

Firstly, you will need to add `jQuery(document).ready()` This is because the image element may not exist at the time of the `javascript` code being executed.

Next, you are missing `jQuery` or `$` before `("#myimg")`.

Finally, make sure that you are including the jQuery js file before you are running your internal js.

See code updated below:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        d = new Date();
        $("#myimg").attr("src","http://i66.tinypic.com/6fme5c.jp?d=" + d.getTime());
    )};
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry if im being petty but *'firstly'* is not a word in english.

Comment: I'm afraid it is, sir. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/first-firstly-or-at-first

Comment: Fair enough. Never ever seen it written down before though ;)

Comment: Learn something new every day :)

Comment: The beauty of Stack Overflow!

Comment: thank you for your fabulous help = still cannot make it work in Dreamweaver::: https://jsfiddle.net/e2mgqemd/

Comment: No problem buddy, if you could upvote and mark this as the answer that would be excellent. If you need any further help, please let me know!